# Trying to get a ggplot to render inside of a reactable table in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactable

I'm trying to get a ggplot to render when clicking a row in a reactable table within a shiny app like seen in this example here:

https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/shiny-demo.html

I have seen the code tab on the link above, but it's missing details that I need.

Here is the code for the reactable table in my shiny app

```
    
    reactable(
        ranks,
        details = function(index) {
          punter_name <- ranks$punter_player_name[index]
          
          gg_df <- punts_2015_2022 %>%
                  filter(punter_player_name == punter_name,
                         season == input$season,
                         season_type == input$season_type) %>%
                  group_by(punter_player_name, posteam, week) %>%
                  summarise(total_FPOE = sum(FPOE, na.rm = T),
                            cumFPOE = cumsum(FPOE)) %>%
                  rename(team_abbr = posteam) %>%
                  left_join(teams_colors_logos)

          ggplot(gg_df, aes(x = week, y = total_FPOE)) +
            geom_point()
```

Running the code like this makes the table disappear when I click the row and no ggplot appear.

Comment: "but it's missing details that I need": Yes, your question also. [Add a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The code tab in the referenced link only contains the `reactable` code but is not a minimal reproducible example, e.g. it misses the part where the plot is actually rendered.

From the code snippet you provided I can only guess that what you are missing is that

1. you have to render the ggplot using a `renderPlot`
2. output the plot using `plotOutput`

whereas in your code the function passed to the `details` argument returns a `ggplot` object.

To get you started the code below is a stripped down example of a minimal Shiny app where

1. I use a `reactive` to filter the data according to the user choice
2. render the plot outside of `reactable` using `renderPlot()`
3. Display the plot inside the `reactable` using `plotOutput()`

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Reactable and ggplot in Shiny"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("species", "Species", unique(iris$Species))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      reactableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris[iris$Species %in% input$species, ]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(Sepal.Length)) +
      geom_histogram()
  })

  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(filtered_data(),
      onClick = "expand",
      details = function(index) {
        if (index == 5) {
          plotOutput("plot")
        }
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]